# Express app continuously logs /sockjs-node/info

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have run the standard express generator like this:

```
express blog --hbs --git
```

And then do an install and try run the app with:

```
cd blog
npm install
DEBUG=blog:* npm start
```

The app starts, and I can see the loading page in the browser, however I constantly get the following log lines being printed:

```
GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1459184976170 404 54.682 ms - 1060
GET /sockjs-node/info?t=1459184981971 404 8.142 ms - 1060
```

Why is this, is there a problem with the configuration?
How do I rectify this?

Express generator - http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: Seems like you have socks-nodejs running somewhere. Could you run netstat -tulpn, to see which ports are in use.

Comment: I think this was the problem, things worked after a reboot...

Comment: just the same problem... reboot helped

Comment: It also happens if you ran another app on the same port and left the browser page opened. In that case, just close that browser page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple reboot fixed the problem... it's likely that Daurens solution in the comments would also work, but I can't confirm that.

Just turn it off and on again...